# Regex match pair query string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this:

> prikey = 2, ju = 20150101, name = sdf, email = sdfsdf@naver.com, sub = (한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장, 1항기, 사 채용

I wanna split each pair like this:

> 1. prikey=2
> 2. ju=20150101
> 3. name=sdf
> 4. email=sdfsdf@naver.com
> 5. sub=(한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장, 1항기, 사 채용

I tried this code:

```
/((?:[^=,]+)=(?:[^=]+)),/g
```

But it doesn't work fine.

> 1. prikey=2
> 2. ju=20150101
> 3. name=sdf
> 4. email=sdfsdf@naver.com
> 5. sub=(한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장

Comment: Try `/([^,]*)/g`. Or you can just use `str.split(",");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely be able to capture what you want with a pattern such as:

```
(?:,)\s|([^=]+=\s[\w@\.\s]+|[\w].+)
```

**Result**:

```
prikey = 2 
ju = 20150101 
name = sdf
email = sdfsdf@naver.com
sub = (한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장, 1항기, 사 채용
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/sP5sB8/1

**Code**:

http://jsfiddle.net/df06waLd/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `str.split(', ')`

```js
var str = 'prikey = 2, ju = 20150101, name = sdf, email = sdfsdf@naver.com, sub = (한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장, 1항기, 사 채용';

var result = str.split(', ');
var wanted = [];

result.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.indexOf('=') !== -1) {
    wanted.push(el);
  } else {
    wanted[wanted.length - 1] += ', ' + el;
  }
})

console.log(wanted);
```

And you will get:

```
["prikey = 2", "ju = 20150101", "name = sdf", "email = sdfsdf@naver.com", "sub = (한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장, 1항기, 사 채용"]
```

Comment: who voted down leave a comment to say some reason please. :)

Comment: `result[4] == sub = (한진해운) 2014년도 케미컬 선장, 사 채용, 1항기` which is not what OP want. And this answer depends on the number of `,`s in the last item.

Comment: @JackDuong Update the answer. How about this one?

Comment: @falsetru Sorry for my mistakes. I updated the answer and now the result depends on whether the string contains of a '='. I suppose that regular expression may work but it would be complicate, so I want to use a programming way...